# Disputes about content on question?

Tags: support, locked-questions

I asked for help on the website for a question and I gave out more context to it but instead my question was locked until further notice. Why?

Answer (score 7):

As Gareth mentioned in the comments:

> Ah, if this comes from an ongoing contest then I'm afraid we can't have it here until after the contest is over. It seems like that's one week from when it was posted, which I think was Sunday, so I'm going to lock this for a week. After that it's fair game.
>
> (The lock message talks about "disputes about its content"; of course there's no actual dispute. There's a fixed set of messages available and this was the closest.)

Questions that are part of an ongoing contest or competition are not allowed on this site - they are locked until the contest is over.